# Using MVC Core Api RequestModel with GET Request and how should URI look like?

Tags: c#, rest, api, asp.net-core-mvc, restful-url

Consider the following example:

```
[HttpGet("api/values/{id}")]
public ActionResult<string> Get(int id)
{
    return id
}
```

The above will work without problems, however, I wish to change that so that it allows lets say for argument sake 10 parameters. I'm trying to understand in a restful api scenario how this is accomplished.

The first question is how its suppose to look like on the URI side? `api/values/5/testOne/TestTwo/`? What if testOne is null? So should I use Query Parameters then? `api/values/5/?testOne=abc&testTwo=123`

The second is can I wrap it in what I call a request Model. Example:
Lets say I have a request model like this:

```
public class TestRequestModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string TestOne { get; set; }
    public string TestTwo { get; set; }
}
```

And lets say I wish to include it:

```
[HttpGet("api/values/{id}/{testOne}/{testTwo}")]
public ActionResult<string> Get(TestRequestModel requestModel)
{
    return requestModel.Id
}
```

The above {id} will not map to requestModle.Id, nor will the other parameters. My second question is how do I achieve that binding in a GET request?

Comment: Try `api/values/5//TestTwo/` to pass `null` to the `testOne` parameter in URL.

Comment: Use `[FromRoute] TestRequestModel requestModel`.

Comment: @KirkLarkin does that work with query strings or only setup route?

Comment: That's for the "setup route" (your second example).

Answer (score 0):

While setting urls according to rest practises you can get url parameters like this

```
[HttpGet("api/values/{id:int}/{testOne:(type)}/{testTwo(type)}")]
```

You should set type types unless the query parameter is not string. And, you can get those values like that

```
HttpGet("api/values/{id:int}/{testOne:type}/{testTwo:type}")]
public ActionResult<string> Get(int id, type testOne, type testTwo)
{
    TestRequest model = new TestRequestModel();
    request.id = id;
    request.TypeOne = typeOne;
    .....
}
```

The reason we mapped query parameters explicitly is that there is no native support in .net to map query parameters to class. Also you could get required values from a class and using that type to get parameters. But in this way, you should set those parameters in FormData, not in query string. Hope this helps.

Comment: In an MVC View application you can do this, are you saying in an API application you can't? It just doesn't seem right...

Comment: I am not saying you can not do this. You can do for both.

Comment: Ok, how? My original question was asking how do you accomplish that.

Comment: With the code I demonstrate in my comment, you can achieve that I suppose. Whether its a mvc endpoint or api endpoıint, its is common practice to add unique identifiier of the controller in the url.  In your case, I beleive it is id variable. Also, the variables in your code(testOne, testTwo) is mapped to input parameters(as I have shown in my comment) but again, I do NOT think you can map those variables directly to your class.